# Produce vertex displacements from volumetric shrinkage data on unstructured meshes

Tags: finite-element, computational-geometry, finite-volume, mesh, heat-transfer

I was wondering what would be an efficient way to produce compatible displacements for mesh nodes/vertices if the computed data is volume shrinkage of each element/cell in the unstructured mesh?

Probably similar is done when one calculates thermal expansion of the material, and then has to produce nodal displacements and stresses, the thermal expansion produces. Basically it should be the same algorithm I suppose.

Thanks.

Comment: You want this displacement to have a mesh deformation during your simulation or you want it just for visualization to show the displacement?

Comment: It would be used during the simulation.

Comment: So you want to use a Lagrangian grid instead of a fixed Eulerian one right?

Comment: No just want to incorporate mesh motion in Eulerian frame. At least one boundary is fixed btw.

Comment: But Eulerian grid means the points should stay at their position all the time. What do you want to simulate? Probably if you simply move Eulerian grid points during the simulation your numerical framework will become unstable and will generate incorrect results. It's just my guess cause usually people use Lagrangian grids for incorporating the mesh deformation into the computational framework, which is not really easy I believe. Which software you use for simulation?

Comment: Ok now I get it what were you asking. Yes I will have mesh deformation, but I think it's not central to the question, the difficulty is transforming volume shrinkage which is a data pertinent to element/cell to nodal displacements.

Comment: Oh, ok. So if I get you correctly your question is: how you want to convert volume shrinkage, which is **cell** data, to nodal or **point** data right?

Comment: Correct @Alone Programmer, in compatible way.

Comment: OK, do you have access to VTK or your framework is somehow aware of VTK library?

Comment: Yes, but I am aware of their filters like 'Cell data to node data', it wont work because volume shrinkage is given by percent of original volume, it's not something that can be simply interpolated.

Comment: OK, but volume shrinkage $\frac{\Delta V}{V}$ is just the trace of strain tensor right? $$\frac{\Delta V}{V} = \mathrm{Tr}(\varepsilon)$$, where $\varepsilon$ is strain tensor. So, why you think that parameter can't be converted to nodal value simply by using interpolation?

Comment: It seems you are on the right track, please consider submitting the whole answer.

Comment: Okie dokie! I'm gonna get lunch now but I'll submit my answer when I come back :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101904/discussion-between-johntra-volta-and-alone-programmer).

Answer (score 1):

Based on our discussion in the comments, it seems `vtkCellDataToPointData` is what you want to convert volume shrinkage, which is stored as **cell** data, to nodal values or **point** data. I think it's possible cause volume shrinkage ($\frac{\Delta V}{V}$) is defined as trace of strain tensor and there is no reason that that parameter can't be interpolated to the nodes present in your mesh:

$$\frac{\Delta V}{V} = \mathrm{Tr}(\varepsilon)$$

Note that `vtkCellDataToPointData` use only **linear** interpolation cause it doesn't know anything about the basis function of your FEM mesh. If you already know what's the basis function of your mesh in your FEM scheme you might want to use that for interpolation instead of using simple linear one that could be done automatically by VTK. The last thing, which might be important for you to use `vtkCellDataToPointData` is that this class has an attribute function as `SetContributingCellOption` where you can specify which cells or mesh would contribute to calculate the nodal values. For example, in your specific situation when you want to calculate **volume** shrinkage, it doesn't make sense to have contribution from 2D or 1D cells and only 3D cells (e.g. tetrahedrals, hexahedrons, etc.) should contribute for calculating the nodal values of **volume** shrinkage. You can specify which cells contribute to calculate the nodal values by using `SetContributingCellOption` function. I hope it helps you.